# Mobile-website image loading a bit random

Tags: mobile

Sometimes images (jpg) load on my mobile-website and sometimes they don't. Sometimes a page that loaded images before, stops doing so.  After I updated some text on my Gallery page it stopped loading (or would take about 5 minutes).My Services page with images loaded fine. To test it, I copied  an image address from my Services page to my Gallery page and uploaded the Gallery page.  After a few minutes it worked on the Gallery page but it wouldn't load on the Services page. A few minutes more and it worked on the Services page but not on the Gallery page. Does this mean it is something to do with my hosting service?

Comment: Hey, just a heads up, this post is probably going to get voted to be closed since it's not really a programming issue, and if it is its' very broad with no real details for us to assist you. I recommend contacting your hosting service provider for help IF you are using their built in "website builder" tools which it sounds like you might be.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I am not using a website builder by the way. I have just found in my page source the following: <script pagespeed_no_defer="">//<![CDATA[(function({varg=encodeURIComponent,h=window,k=document,l="width",m="document......................it goes on for thousands of characters.

The page is littered with these scripts. My host must be putting it there, unless it because I installed google analytics. I don't know what pagespeed is but it seems to be slowing things down.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been fixed. It turns out it was nothing to do with my coding or image sizes. I asked my host to deactivate pagespeed for me and everything is once again fine. All backgrounds and images loading perfectly, (on my mobile anyhow). Pagespeed had to be deactivated from my whole account not just the mobile section. I don't think I'll miss it but I'm going to try and minify my html, css and javascript to try and speed things up anyway.